# Is there a way to add a locale with the ISO-8859-1 character encoding?

Tags: ubuntu, locale

When doing `locale -av` on Lubuntu, the result returned shows that all of the locales uses the UTF-8 character encoding.

Is there a way to add a locale with the ISO-8859-1 character encoding?

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that the ISO-8859-1 locale is supported, but just hasn't been generated. From [the third answer of this Ask Ubuntu page:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server)

1. Check which locales are supported:

   ```
   less /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED
   ```
2. Add the language that you want to `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local`. Generally, a language locale that is not suffixed (e.g. `en_CA` instead of `en_CA.UTF-8`) is ISO-8859-1, but you can add a specific codepage if you want as well:

   ```
   # Change 'en_CA' to the locale that you want
   echo en_CA >> /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local
   echo en_CA.ISO-8859-1 >> /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local
   ```
3. Regenerate the locale data:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
   ```

Comment: On my ElementaryOS machine (Ubuntu 18.04 based), adding a value to `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` didn't work, but the `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` command brings up an ncurses gui, and selecting the relevant locale there did resolve my (similar) issues.